# People keep describing algebras as though evaluation takes expressions back to the set of generators and I don't get it

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, universal-algebra, type-theory

Let $F$ be the free monoid functor, and $G$ its right adjoint. Then $G \circ F$ is a monad on $\mathbf{Set}$; and its unit $\eta$ is a natural transformation taking every set $X$ to the set $(G \circ F) X$ ("set of words on the alphabet $X$") in such a way that every element $x$ in $X$ is mapped to its "singleton word" $[x]$. "Insertion of generators."

When it comes to building an algebra to go back the other way, however, I'm lost. An algebra for this monad should be a morphism from the set $(G \circ F) X$ back to $X$. Supposedly these morphisms $(G \circ F) X \to X$ are going to represent the various possible monoid operations on $(G \circ F) X$. But how does that work? Monoid operations do not, in general, map back to the set of the monoid's generators!

To use a concrete example: If $X = \{a, b, c\}$, then the unit of the monoid free-forgetful monad will map $X$ to $T X = \{[], [a], [b], [c], [a, a], [a, b], ... \}$ in precisely the following way: $\{a \to [a], b \to [b], c \to [c]\}$. How on earth would an arbitrary monoid algebra map $T X$ back to $X$ ?

Every time I see these sort of "free-forgetful $\mathbf{Set}$ $T$-algebras" explained online, for example in computer science, people seem to say things like, "Oh, for a set $X$ you use the free structure in $T$ to build up a *formal* expression, with the *formal* operations, of elements of $X$. Then for a given $\theta$ for that $T X$, you substitute specific "real" operations in for the formal ones and evaluate." But why should such an evaluation get you back to an element of $X$? In particular, if your "real" operations that you evaluate after subbing in for the formal ones are *the formal operations themselves*, I can't see how you generally get back an element of the generator set or anything obviously corresponding to it.

I haven't even managed to understand the always-reliable Eugenia Cheng on this matter. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBQnysX7oLI&feature=youtu.be&t=272) she writes out "$(a, b, c, d)$" as an example element of $T A$, the set of "words"; presumably, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are supposed to be elements of $A$, the generators of the free monoid whose elements $T A$ is the set of. But then she says that her algebra $\theta$ is supposed to take this "word" $(a, b, c, d)$ to $abcd \in A$ ("the result of multiplying all these things in a row").

In [the subsequent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYY5c1kkoIo) she supposedly clarifies that, indeed, the juxtaposition notation was intended to represent the particular monoid multiplication provided by the algebra $\theta$. But again, this is no clarification for me, because I can't see any reason why the result of that multiplication *should* be an element of $A$. She does call $A$ the "*underlying* set" in this video; and I have a feeling that this cuts to the core of what I'm not understanding, because I'm not getting how that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion is that that $T$-algebra structure described by a map $TX \to X$ is not an algebra on $TX$, rather one on $X$!

In your case, it's monoid structures over $X$ that we're interested in, note those on $(G\circ F)X$ (I'll use $T=G\circ F$)

Then, the formal expression $x_1x_2 \in TX$ for instance, has no meaning in $X$. But once we endow $X$ with a monoid structure, that is a multiplication $\times$, then we can say that $x_1x_2 \mapsto x_1\times x_2$ (and similarly for more complex formal expressions). This yields a map $TX\to X$ that corresponds to the given monoid structure.

Conversely, given a sufficiently nice map $h:TX\to X$, we can think of it as being induced by a monoid structure on $X$; indeed it then suffices to define $x_1 \times x_2$ as $h(x_1x_2)$ (where $x_1x_2 \in TX$ is the formal expression). The niceness assumption on $X$ (given by the $T$-algebra axioms) allow one to prove that this does indeed yield a monoid structure.

Moreover these two processes (from a monoid structure get a nice map $TX\to X$, and from a nice map $TX\to X$ get a monoid structure) are inverse to one another.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused. $X$ is just a set, no? Not endowed with any structure at all. We started talking about structure when we used the free functor $F$ to take $X$ over to $\mathbf{Mon}$. But that's not a structure *on* the elements of $X$; it's a structure *generated* by the elements of $X$. It's got far more elements than just those in $X$ for sure! So what we have with $T = G \circ F$, as it takes $X$ back to $\mathbf{Set}$, is that big underlying set of those elements.

Eugenia Cheng says at the beginning of [Monads 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBQnysX7oLI):

Comment: "One way of thinking about it is that the *monad*, the action of the functor, gives us all the operations that, in principle, are needed in this theory; and, when we have an *algebra* it tells us, in this particular case, how we're actually going to evaluate, where we're going to find those operations, what are they, what do they do..."

Comment: ...Well, it looks to me like the monad is giving us a monoid structure (explicitly, a free monoid, and thus presumably other monoids by subbing different multiplications in) *generated* by $X$, not *on* $X$. $T X$ is the underlying set of *this* monoid. How is a monoid structure *on* $T X$, merely *generated* by $X$, providing the general template for the monoid structures *on* $X$ (as Cheng seems to suggest)?

Comment: The *monad* doesn't give any monoid structure on $X$, the $T$-algebra is a monoid structure on $X$ ! $TX$ by itself is just a set too, it simply happens to also be endowed with a natural $T$-algebra structure, which makes it into a monoid (the so-called free monoid on $X$).But a $T$-algebra structure on $X$ is precisely a monoid structure on $X$. That's what Cheng says : "when we have an algebra". So what's important is not the monoid structure on $TX$, nor $X$, it's the $T$-algebra structure on $X$, i.e. the nice map $h: TX\to X$

Comment: To emphasize and clarify I hope, the overall statement is **if** you have or make a monoid structure on $X$ **then** there is a corresponding $T$-algebra, i.e. map $TX \to X$ satisfying the $T$-algebra laws. Each monoid structure on $X$ will give a different $T$-algebra. Conversely, *given* a $T$-algebra $h : TX \to X$, we can make a monoid structure on $X$. Namely, we define the unit to be $h([])$ and the binary multiplication to be $(x,y)\mapsto h([x,y])$. It is a good exercise from here to show that the $T$-algebra laws imply that these definitions satisfy the monoid laws.

Comment: @Max Wait. You say, $T X$ is a set "endowed with a natural $T$-algebra structure, which makes it a monoid, the so-called free monoid on $X$"? Yes! That part makes perfect sense to me. $T X$, not $X$, is the set endowed with the monoid structure commonly known as "the free monoid on $X$." But then in the very next sentence you say that "a $T$-algebra structure on $X$" is "precisely a monoid structure on $X$", not $T X$. That is what has been confusing me.

Comment: @DerekElkins Let me see if I'm starting to get it...
Cheng had been talking about *monads* for two videos. And the monad $T$ is "produced" by / associated with a particular monoid: the so-called "free monoid on (i.e. generated by) $X$." However when she now talks about "the monad [$T$] giving us all the operations that are needed in this theory," she's still talking about the *monoid* algebraic structure, but now she's talking about such structures on a completely different set...

Comment: @DerekElkins For each potential monoid structure we might impose *on $X$ itself*, there is a $\mathbf{Set}$-morphism mapping each element of the free monoid *generated by* $X$ (therefore borne by a *completely different set* than $X$) to an element of $X$; and this $\mathbf{Set}$-morphism distinguishes a monoid *on $X$*: One element of $X$ is designated the "unit" and mapped to by $[]$ (and, for all we might devise, perhaps more or even every element of $T X$), and so forth, because every possible "multiplication" of $X$- elements is expressed by an element of the free monoid generated by $X$.

Comment: @DerekElkins ...And this is what $T$-algebras are all about. Loosely, "using" a free structure *generated* by a set to come up with a structure of the same "signature" *on* that set itself, this being possible because all possible "trees" of elements and operations of the structure-endowed set are expressed by the elements of the free structure *generated* by it.

Comment: Yes, the natural $T$-algebra structure on $TX$ makes it a monoid, and if you find a $T$ algebra structure on $X$, this makes $X$ into a monoid. But I think your comments responding to Derek Elkins show you've understood that by now ?

Comment: @Max Been very helpful; let me see if I've got it at long last. As a loose intuition... you are basically using the map from the free monoid's underlying set to pick out a "multiplication table" with values in the set used to generate the free monoid in the first place?

Comment: @Max ...Like for instance if $X = \{a, b, c\}$ then $(G \circ F) X = \{[], [a], [b], [c], [aa], [ab], [ba], ...\}$ and a mapping from $(G \circ F) X$ would use those elements to pick out, respectively, a "unit," an "$a$" a "$b$," a "$c$," the value of a "monoid multiplication" of $a \ast b$, and so forth, from among the elements of $X$(all according to the coherence laws between the algebra and monad, of course) thus determining a monoid structure to impose on $X$.

Comment: Well you don't get to pick "$a,b$ and $c$", because théy're fixed (but that's imposed by the coherence conditions anyway, as you may like to check) , but essentially yes, picking a nice map $TX\to X$ is like picking a multiplication table, thus determining a monoid structure on $X$

Answer (score 2):

A change of perspective that might help clarify things it to look at the corresponding comonad on the category of algebras.

Suppose you have a monoid $M$. The counit is a monoid homomorphism $(F \circ G)M \to M$.

- $GM$ has the interpretation of being the underlying set of elements of $M$.
- $(F \circ G)M$ has the interpretation of being the monoid of formal operations applied to the elements of $M$

and the counit $(F \circ G)M \to M$ is simply the "evaluation" homomorphism that replaces the formal operations with their actual values.

Now, let's apply $G$ again, so that we can look at this whole arrangement in terms of the underlying sets. The evaluation map is sent to $(G \circ F \circ G)M \to GM$.

If we define $X = GM$, then evaluation is a map $TX \to X$ which, in fact, satisfies the definition of a $T$-algebra.

The interpretation is now

- $X$ is the underlying set of a monoid
- $TX$ is the set of all formal operations on the elements of that monoid
- $TX \to X$ evaluates the formal operations